# How do I create a charge on a Stripe customer from a connected account

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm creating a type of ride-sharing application for iOS using Swift and Firebase Functions and would like to implement the following workflow:

1. Passenger requests ride from specific driver
2. Driver has 2 options

a. Driver accepts and the passengers card is charged

b. Driver declines and thats it

I've gone through pages and pages of Stripes documentation and Github to find the best example to go off, but can't seem to find one that fits what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

There's also https://rocketrides.io/ which is a complete example, including code, of a ride sharing app.